# How do I make my web page work with the same layout in all browsers?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make my web page work with the same layout (height, width, etc.) in all browsers, using JavaScript.  How can I do this?

by the way i tried to use percentage value

Comment: The vagueness of this question tempts me to vote to close. Usually consistent layout would not be acheived using javascript, except in some borderline cases. Why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: Ah yes, cross browser compatibility, the modern day Vietnam within web development.

Answer (score 2):

Please read the *Dao of Web Design*, an article written in 2000.
The Dao is that web design should not, nor need to, look identical in all browsers. This is not print design. I find that most designers do not understand this and spin their wheels trying to control a medium that is not meant to be controlled. Design your sites to fit within the imperfect construct rather than trying to make an imperfect medium perfect.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dao/

Comment: This isn't correct IMO, and quite a dated way of development.  With JQuery and a number of techniques, there's no excuse for loss of cross browser compatibility (unless we're talking ie6 lol)

Answer (score 0):

I use this script quite a bit for users who use IE6 and IE7 (also works for IE8)

http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

I'd combine that with a CSS reset, and you'd be in business.